# Click-function firing on page load despite all efforts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pulling my hair out on this...

I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.element-anchor').click(function(e){
        scrollToTop(e, this);
    });
});

function scrollToTop(event, elem){
    event.preventDefault();
    // do stuff
}
```

The Scroll-Top Event is fired on page load already.

I also tried `$('a.element-anchor').on('click', function(){...});`

Nothing helps. The event always fires on page load.

What am I doing wrong???

[Edit]

The Anchor looks like this:

```
<a href="#top" data-title="Link Title" class="element-anchor" id="anAnchor"></a>
```

It might be that the URL is interfering with it:

```
http://www.example.com/action=doSomeStuff#anAnchor
```

So the browser is supposed to jump to #anAnchor when the page is loaded and an action is supposed to be executed (fetching the var from the URL)

Comment: Can you post your HTML. I have used `<a class="element-anchor" href="#">Click</a>` and your JS code, and it doesn't fire on load.

Comment: I editet my question with more details how the link looks

Comment: Looks like `href="#top"` triggers the scroll. Try after removing that.

Comment: @code-jaff: didn't help - click is still executed.

Comment: When I point the #anAnchor to a different ID, it works without the click-event being triggered... weird...

Answer (score 0):

You might have some other JavaScript code triggering it. To help find out more about what's happening, try pausing your browser's developer tools on the scrollToTop function. The easiest way to do this in a development environment is to add this statement inside your function:

`debugger;`

This will open up the developer tools and pause execution when the function runs, and from there you can inspect the stack trace.

Comment: I tried that - all I can see is that the click-event is triggered. But it doesn't tell me what triggered it.

Answer (score -1):

Could try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.element-anchor').on('click', function(e){
     scrollToTop(e, this);
  });
});
```

Comment: ~~deleted accidental comment~~